# what is file usr/lib/opkg/info/initscripts.list

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, kernel

What is the purpose of  usr/lib/opkg/info/initscripts.list file in file system. 
And from where it's being called ?

Comment: That is not in my kernel tree.  Are you sure this is related to kernel programming?

Comment: not related to kernel programming but related to file system....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file /usr/lib/opkg/info/.list tracks the data files (images/files in data.tar.gz) in your archive.

For example:

```
say your debian package contains control.tar.gz and data.tar.gz and these folder contents looks like this,

Package control data (control.tar.gz)
    |
    |-control
    |-postinst
    |-preinst
Upstream data(data.tar.gz)
    |
    |-package-image1
    |-package-image2
    |-packge-config-file
    |-packe-readme-file
```

then /usr/lib/opkg/info/.list contains,

```
    package-image1
    package-image2
    packge-config-file
    packe-readme-file
```

Note:
 Usually /usr/lib/opkg/info/ contains following files,

```
<package-name>.control       ----> package control information (version,architecture....) 
<package-name>.list          ----> package data files information (files/images in data.tar.gz)
<package-name>.preinst       ----> package pre install script
<package-name>.postinst      ----> package post install script
```